# swiftui アラート Missing argument for parameter 'text' in call

Tags: swift

swift ui でContentViewからサイドメニューに移動しようとするときに

```
SideMenuView(isOpen: $isOpenSideMenu)
```

と書くと

```
Missing argument for parameter 'text' in call
```

と

```
Insert ', text: <#Binding<String>#>'
```

というエラーが出ます。

```
#Binding<String>
```

は必要ですか？

`#Binding<String>`を付け足しましたが、余分なので付けたくないです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SideMenuViewが何なのかはわかりませんが、textという引数は省略できません。

ですが、こういった初期化方法もあります。

```swift
SideMenuView(isOpen: $isOpenSideMenu, text: .constant(""))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。これに関するエラーは出なくなりました。ですが、他のエラーが出るようになったので、そちらを確認したいと思います。SideMenuViewはstructです。